# Does the 'Research Assistant' badge now count tag excerpt edits?

Tags: support, badges, tag-wiki-excerpt

From the [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484/1017231):

> the badge counts distinct tag wikis you edit **excluding excerpts**

and the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/1017231):

> Edits to tag wiki excerpts **do not count** [emphasis mine; thanks @bobble]

**Update:** I've now updated both links above with the answer explaining the "oddity".

Before, creating/editing tag *excerpts* **never** counted towards the *Research Assistant* badge as shown above, now recently they started to, while the description hasn't changed:

> Edit 50 tag wikis.

Is it an [unannounced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=research%20assistant) change that needs reflection in the description?
Or a bug?
Or **was** a bug and is now fixed (excerpts suddenly being part of wikis)?

Also semantically, a book excerpt is **not** a book.

I noticed the change very recently, because I was 48/50 and that badge's progress is always on my profile, and two excerpt edits later ([latest](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/radome/info)), I just got the badge (not here).

> [image]

---

Repro #1: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9014885#9014885 (thanks @MetaAndrewT.)

PS there were no pending wiki edits; I've had the editing privileges for years, in fact I made [**only one** suggestion ever](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/14897/ymb1?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), and it wasn't tag related.

Comment: @sonic: from what I read in the answer/comments, the staff are not sure how they'll handle it yet, can we put [bug] back?

Comment: [tag:support] is a valid tag for things that may be bugs but you aren't sure, per its tag wiki. [tag:possible-bug] is a synonym of that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it does not. What you are seeing is an oddity in how we store tag wikis and their excerpts. One cannot exist without the other. Whenever one is created, the other has to be created.

Since you are a [trusted user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), when you edited those excerpts, you also edited the tag wikis for them because they did not exist yet. You essentially were recorded as creating an empty tag wiki.

For users without the privilege to edit tag wikis directly, we don't use their name for that creation and the creation is instead attributed to the Community user (for both the wiki and the excerpt) and their change is applied as a suggested edit (so long as there is a change; if there is no change from the initial blank revision or a later revision with content, no suggested edit is created).

So if you both have the privilege to edit tag wikis without approval and are editing the excerpt of a non-existent tag wiki, you essentially get a free "edit" from the creation of the tag wiki being attributed to you, even if it's empty. It is not counting the excerpt in any way.

We could probably fix this by adding "and Body is not empty" to the query if needed.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's because the tag excerpt was empty? Or because I created a tag?

Comment: @ymb1 It's essentially counting [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/89181/revisions) as an edit you made to a tag wiki.

Comment: 13:08:12z matches the edit to excerpt indeed, not the tag creation. Gotcha, thanks. I thought a tag creation creates an empty wiki and thus that.

Comment: So this is why [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168852/the-user-who-first-created-a-tag-wiki-is-treated-as-owner-for-suggested-edits), which allows a user who made a binding edit to create a tag wiki or excerpt, the authority to bindingly review future suggested edits on them, occurs. I think that's not supposed to be how it works (in fact, this was fixed for the override feature so only mods could use it).

Comment: @Sonic Mhmmm. Not ever recording the editor as the owner of the tag wiki would also resolve this badge issue.