# Unfollowing a question triggers a "you're no longer following this answer" pop-up

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, popups, follow-post

Seen on mobile web, Brave browser version 1.27.109, Android 10, cannot confirm on other browsers (yet).

Following, then unfollowing a *question* triggers a pop-up reading:

> You're no longer following this **answer**

[image: pop-up reading "you're no longer following this answer"]

Presumably this should read "you're no longer following this question", or "this post", at the very least.

The post in the image is [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369712/398063), which at the time of writing does not have any answers, deleted or otherwise.

---

Searching for `[bug] follow question answer` and sorting by newest ([query link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bbug%5d%20follow%20answer%20question)) did not bring up any obvious duplicate.

Comment: upvoted but not sure if they will fix it since mobile views are getting deprecated and they have mentioned they will be adding [tag:status-declined] to any mobile-only bug reports. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views

Comment: @Cave I don't have access to a computer at the moment. If you do, can you please edit the post to state whether this happens on computers as well? If so, then we can remove the `[mobile-web]` tag

Comment: I tried it in both the mobile and responsive theme and only the mobile theme is affected.

Comment: This issue appears to affect only mobile views. In order to determine the post type, SE uses `$followBtn.hasClass('js-follow-question');`. Apparently, that class is missing from the follow button on mobile.

Comment: @Jenayah You can try reproducing this by clicking the “full site” link in the footer.

Comment: Confirmed on a phone (FF Browser), when you use the full site you get a different message than the mobile site provides for exactly the same action, [unfollowing a question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoqUD.jpg). The [tag:mobile-web] tag is correctly used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now fixed.

> Unfollow question
> correct confirmation showed
> while in mobile view